# Finding Fibonacci matrix's eigenvectors. But I'm algebraic disaster. stucking at calculation.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, fibonacci-numbers

Likewise title, I was calculating eigenvectors of Fibonacci matrix.
I set the Fibonacci matrix to be
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f_{n+1}\\
    f_n
    \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    f_n\\
    f_{n-1}
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}
=M
$$
And by determinant computation, I get the eigenvalues $\lambda = (1\pm\sqrt5)/2$ (I set plus one to $\phi$ and minus one to $\psi$).

And I chose to find the eigenvectors through brute computation searching the kernel space of matrix $(M-\lambda I)$.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1-\phi & 1 \\
1&-\phi
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Which is expressed as above. I though this computation would give me solution for $x$ and $y$. However, instead I got 
$$
(1-\phi)x+y=0
$$
$$x-\phi y=0
$$
which led to
$$(1-\phi+1/\phi)x=0$$
which gave me nothing but faint.

I think I'd faced this kind of error during algebra I'm not sure last time experience was also about Fibonacci or not. However I remember at that time I missed some operation which seems adding no information but still making equation solvable (such as dividing lefthand-side to righthand-side, ...).

I know that there are eigenvectors and How they look like. What I am interested in is how to achieve.
I searched a bit and I found a youtube course. but he just guessed out the vector like mathmagician which is not what im looking for.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wPEB2XDMJo (It's around 19:50~)
Please help me Hyper math bois..

Comment: $\phi$ is supposed to be $\lambda$, that is, $(1\pm\sqrt5)/2$ . You substitute the values in the equation and solve. A matrix $M$ has a nontrivial kernel if and only if its determinant is zero. The first step is to solve for the eigenvalues $\lambda$, the second step is to compute the kernel for  $M -\lambda I$, going over those $\lambda$.

Comment: @user3257842 But how? (1−ϕ+1/ϕ)x=0 isn't this mean that x=0???.

Comment: I'm definitely missed something.

Comment: $(1−ϕ+1/ϕ) = 0$ when $ϕ = (1\pm\sqrt5)/2$ . What weird is that you computed $\lambda$ correctly, but you didn't use $\lambda = ϕ$. You're supposed to use the eigenvalues you computed in the previous step.

Comment: @user3257842 now I know what I missed. but thanks for helping!

Comment: aditionally, if $(x,y)$ is an eighenvector, then so is $(k*x , k*y)$, for any  scalar $k$. So for example you may need to set $x=1$ to obtain a value for $y$.

Comment: The golden ratio has the property that its multiplicative inverse has the same decimal part as itself. So $1 - \phi$ is $-(\phi) - 1$ which is the opposite of the decimal part of $\phi$. And then $1/ \phi$ is the decimal part. SO you add two opposites and get 0

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ is any of the eigenvalues, it is clear that $(\lambda,1)$ is a solution of the equation $x-\lambda x=0$. Is it also a solution of the equation $(1-\lambda)x+y=0$? Yes, because this is the same thing as asserting that$$(1-\lambda)\lambda+1=0,$$or$$\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0.\tag1$$And the eigenvalues are the roots of the equation $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

When you get to

$(1-\phi+(1/\phi))x=0$

you're right on target.  The coefficient of $x$ on the left side is zero because your eigenvalue equation is $\phi^2-\phi-1=0$ and the coefficients just $1-\phi+(1/\phi)=-(\phi^2-\phi-1)/\phi$.  So your equation really says "Put anything you want for $x$", then once you've chosen you solve for $y$.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh right... eigenvectors can be multiplied by scalar.
My brain must be damaged.
thank you now I know.